# d3 v4 scale returning incorrect values

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

I am trying to plot a scatter plot with with a variable containing json. I have about 800 points to plot.
This is my of code:

```
var data = json_games;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 400},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Component1 = +d.Component1;
  d.Component2 = +d.Component2;
 });

 var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {  return d.Component1; }),d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Component1; })]);
 var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]).domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.Component2; }),d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Component2; })]);


// Add the scatterplot
g.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.Component1); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.Component2); });

// Add the X Axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

As the data is huge in order to find the maximum and minimum values of x and y components I used cgrome console and the values that I am getting are as follows:

```
>d3.min(data, function(d) {  return d.Component1; })
>-0.20829495230931433
>d3.max(data, function(d) {  return d.Component1; })
>0.35130959917777926
>d3.min(data, function(d) {  return d.Component2; })
>-1.2035701018868445
>d3.max(data, function(d) {  return d.Component2; })
>0.7208057297018022

and the scaled values of x and y that I am getting are:
x(0.6)
>1169.967094854204
y(0.6)
>468.6117109457583
```

Because of this the points in the scatterplot are being drawn in corners.
Can someone please help. I also tried d3.extent but with the same values.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not following this: why are you doing `x(0.6)`? This is more than the max value.

Comment: Ooh my bad. Even if I put something in range it will get skewed. Just like y 0.6 is less than max but I am getting  468 as the scaled value

Comment: It seems ok to me. What are the values of `height` and `width`?

Comment: Ooh yes I think the values are fine, buy how should bI generate a more distributed scatter plot. As the values are so close all the points are stacked in the corners

Comment: Can you tell me the `width` and the `height`?

Comment: width is 1240 height is 460

Comment: Ok, I just put the exact values that you have for your domain and range and I'm getting a **different** value, which is the correct one. At this point, the only way to help you is if you post a **working** code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139989/discussion-between-mayur-jadhav-and-gerardo-furtado).